# Tree Diagram including skipping parts

Tags: python, tree

Consider 3 numbers like (2,3,4), these will not differ depending on the depth of the tree. So a tree with depth three will generate:

```
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 2 4
2 3 2
2 3 3
2 3 4
2 4 2
2 4 3
2 4 4
3 2 2
3 2 3
3 2 4
3 3 2
3 3 3
3 3 4
3 4 2
3 4 3
3 4 4
4 2 2
4 2 3
4 2 4
4 3 2
4 3 3
4 3 4
4 4 2
4 4 3
4 4 4
```

In essence it is a cartesian product. I found multiple ways to generate these trees, for example, these two:

```
size = [2, 3, 4]
depth = 3
pos = [size] * depth

#method 1
for element in itertools.product(*pos):
    print element

#method 2
def product(*args):
    if not args:
        return iter(((),)) # yield tuple()
    return (items + (item,) 
            for items in product(*args[:-1]) for item in args[-1])
print list(product(*pos))
```

But they don't allow me to do calculations while creating the tuples.

Imagine you want to filter all results (not only end results) that lead to 7. For example, 2 2 2 is 6 in total so you go to next one 2 2 3 this gives 7. Now you can skip one (you know for sure the next result won't give 7). This skipping part is essential for me, because it saves a lot of time in the calculation.

Another example would be the branch that starts with 4 3, it needs to stop there because that is already 7. So no calculation on the subbranches.

How can I perform calculations during the creation of tuples and decide based on the calculations to skip branches that will definitely surpass 7.

Comment: Please, improve your code to make it reproducible to help us to help you.

Comment: @Juan Antonio Well, the only three lines missing are:

size = [2, 3, 4]
depth = 3
pos = [size] * depth

Then you can use either method 1 or 2 to create a full tree.

Comment: One optimization: you only need to iterate to a depth of `depth - 1`, as there's only one possible value for the last element that sums to your target. Calculate it and check if it's in the list of valid values.